# Migrating Cpanel to new server

Tags: centos, cpanel

I'm in the process of migrating my VPS to a Dedicated server. I initially set up the new box with the correct dedicated server version of cPanel. I transfered all the packages and accounts using the cPanel transfer tool. I then copied wwwacct.conf and cpanel.config so that my settings would be identical. Problem I have now seem to have over written the cPanel version back to the VPS version on the new dedicated server. How do I correct this while retaining my settings?

Answer (score 0):

When I migrate from another server, I configure Tweak Settings manually, is the best way.

A tip: Doesn't forgot to download EasyApache file and recompile in new server with same configuration.